# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

My answer to [this question](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/must-all-claims-be-referenced) was deleted by Borror0:

> I think that most answers will need to
>   be referenced. I have only posted one
>   answer so far that was not referenced.
>   This answer pointed out flaws in other
>   people's logic and pointed out the
>   difficulties with figuring out how
>   difficult the situation is. Ideally I
>   would have referenced this, but these
>   aren't easy ideas to find references
>   for. My argument was too long to post
>   as a comment and I didn't want to
>   allow incorrect ideas to stand
>   unchallenged and so I posted an
>   unreferenced answer.
>
> I think the most important test is
>   whether the answer helps bring us
>   towards the solution - or really just
>   wastes our time.

I don't believe that this was an appropriate use of the moderator power. If there are any issues with this answer, they could have been resolved either by a comment or by making an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question has received the FAQ tag. As such, all but one answer was deleted. The answer left represents the consensus reached by the community. There was no good reason to have the other *eleven other answers* to that question left around, so they were deleted.

From [On adding the FAQ tag to questions](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/413/on-adding-the-faq-tag-to-questions):

> Since those questions will be official policies, they will be cleaned up. We want those questions to be clear and to the point, [like the ones on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).
>
> Expect to see the following changes to those questions as they get elevated to FAQ status:
>
> - Turned into Community Wiki to remove ownership.
> - Edited to remove the specifics, be more concise or clearer.
> - All but one answer deleted.
> - Have all comments deleted.
>
> The purpose of this post is to explain the decision, so that people don't think it's some evil attempt at censorship. It isn't. **We just want those questions to look good** as they will be heavily linked to.