# Ending a discussion as community-wiki

Tags: discussion, moderation, deletion, community-wiki

This question in meta: [Must all claims be referenced](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/24) has been a controversial discussion. Now it is a community-wiki (CW in the following text), and my answer deleted. I don't know whether one action turned it automatically to CW, or whether it was willfully turned into CW. From [the meta of stackexchange on CWs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/156431) I conclude, it wasn't turned automatically, but I might have overseen a possibility.

However, the Wiki-character doesn't play well with a discussion. At least, the discussion tag has to be removed. But I don't suggest that, I suggest to turn it back into a discussion.

In the current state it looks to me, as if somebody doesn't like the topic to be discussed. On said meta-SO page, the purpose of a CW is described as follows:

> One of the goals of the website is to be a continually evolving source of good information. Community Wiki posts help enhance the wiki aspect of the site.

I don't see how this particular page could become a community wiki, especially, if diverging opinions (which where upvoted 5 times) get deleted. It is more like turning the page into a kind of official, undisputable faq.

Answer (score 2):

Your two answers to that question were deleted [because the question was tagged](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/413/on-adding-the-faq-tag-to-questions) [faq](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq):

> Since those questions will be official policies, they will be cleaned up. We want those questions to be clear and to the point, [like the ones on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).
>
> Expect to see the following changes to those questions as they get elevated to FAQ status:
>
> - Turned into Community Wiki to remove ownership.
> - Edited to remove the specifics, be more concise or clearer.
> - All but one answer deleted.
> - Have all comments deleted.
>
> The purpose of this post is to explain the decision, so that people don't think it's some evil attempt at censorship. It isn't. **We just want those questions to look good** as they will be heavily linked to.

As to your other point, I am puzzled as to why you believe it is "a controversial discussion." The three most upvoted answers (scores: 22, 13, 10) all went in the same direction, with usually only minor differences which all are hopefully included in the remaining answer.

On the other hand, your answers had only an handful of upvotes (2 and 3, to be exact). It has seemed, to us, that the community has reached a consensus, which is why it was tagged with the FAQ tag.

With that said, the decision is by no means final. To quote [On adding the FAQ tag to questions](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/413/on-adding-the-faq-tag-to-questions) again:

> FAQ-tagged questions still can be challenged on meta, if deemed necessary.

If you feel this is a discussion we need to have again, or if you'd like to revise the current answer, feel free to start a discussion about it on meta. If the community agrees, the answer will be changed.

Comment: I've removed all comments, the answers are undeleted and the discussion about what consensus means was off-topic anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I've undeleted and moved all the original answers to a [new discussion post](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/discussion-about-requiring-references-for-all-claims) to preserve them. This leaves the FAQ clean and hopefully not too confusing and also preserves all links to the FAQ question.

Answer (score 0):

We have provided some additional guidance at the blog:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

TL;DR version

> Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?” Community wiki is like a cheese knife: it is a specialized tool to be used sparingly, and only in very specific circumstances.

Comment: When would it be appropriate for a mod to make an answer CWiki, then? And if the answer is "basically never", can you remove/disable the CW combo from the mods' edit form?